# What is the meaning on 99.5% uptime SLA if Stack Overflow for Enterprise hosted in our own servers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Following part is copied from [Stack Overflow pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/pricing) page. I didn't understand "Host Anywhere" point with "99.5% uptime SLA" part.

As I know, if it is hosted on our servers, uptime depends on our servers. So what is the meaning of **99.5% uptime SLA**?

> Enterprise
>
> For 500+ users inside large organizations with enterprise-level
>   security and compliance needs.
>
> - Your own Stack Overflow with unlimited Teams
> - **Host anywhere**
> - Single sign-on: AD, SAML
> - Dedicated customer success team
> - **99.5% uptime SLA** & priority support

Answer (score 5):

The *Host Anywhere* is explained as:

> Whether you want to host your community yourself or hand off the reins to us, we’ve got you covered. Host on your cloud, your own servers, or our private managed cloud.

The SLA obviously refers to letting SE host it on their private managed cloud.